# How to get rid off the rectangular selection in SynEdit?

Tags: delphi, synedit

I am using SynEdit installed by the Delphi GetIt Package Manager.

While working with SynEdit, sometimes I get a rectangular selection and do not know how to disable it again. Then I need to restart the program to continue working. I must have pressed some key shortcuts without noticing it.

How can I disable this feature programmatically and/or how to turn off this mode if it was accidentally turned on?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Rectangular Selection]

Comment: [Old sources](https://www.delphipraxis.net/122730-post5.html) tell me you pressed `Alt`. Do it again to toggle. [Others imply](https://sourceforge.net/p/synedit/feature-requests/87/) left-clicking anywhere resets it, too. Not familiar with it, tho.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, indeed it was Ctrl+Shift+C! Thank you so much for your help. To disable the mode, you press Ctrl+Shift+L . 
Can you please post it as answer, then I can mark it as answer.

I think I will try to catch Ctrl+Shift+C via OnKeyDown to "disable" it.

Comment: You can also check if your SynEdit's `Options` contain `eoAltSetsColumnMode` - "Holding down the Alt Key will put the selection mode into columnar format"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called *column select mode*. According to the [source code](https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit/blob/master/Source/SynEditKeyCmds.pas), the hotkey to toggle it on is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. (It's on approximately line 879, which reads

```
AddKey(ecColumnSelect, ord('C'), [ssCtrl,ssShift]);
```

As you indicated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77198576/how-to-get-rid-off-the-rectangular-selection-in-synedit/77199252#comment136094600_77198576) above, you turn off that mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.